# Input validation not working in react onSubmit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having checkbox for citizenship of Indian and Foreigner,

```
submit(){
  if(this.state.citizenship == ""){
        alert("Please Select Citizenship");
        }
  else if(this.state.citizenship == "Indian" ? this.state.ic_no == "" : null){
            alert("Enter Adhar Number");
        }

        else if(this.state.citizenship == "Foreigner" ? this.state.passport_no == "" : null){
            alert("Enter Passport Number");
        }
  else {
    let data ={
             ic_no: this.state.ic_no,
             passport_no: this.state.passport_no,
             citizenship: this.state.citizenship,

            }

  }
}



 this.state = {
    ic_no: '',
    passport_no: '',
    citizenship: '',
 }




 <div className="form-group row p-l-5">
   <div className="col-md-4">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="Citizenship" value="Indian" onChange={this.CitizenshipChange.bind(this)} /> &nbsp;
             <label>Indian</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-8">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="Citizenship" value="Foreigner" onChange={this.CitizenshipChange.bind(this)} /> &nbsp;
                <label>Foreigner</label>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
{
    this.state.citizenship == "Foreigner" ?  <div className="form-group">
    <label className="col-md-12">Passport No 
     </label>
    <div className="col-md-12">
        <input className="form-control"  type="text" onChange={this.passport_noChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.passport_no}/>
    </div>
</div> : null

}


{
    this.state.citizenship == "Indian" ? <div className="form-group">
    <label className="col-md-12">IC No 
    </label>
    <div className="col-md-12">
        <input className="form-control"  type="text" onChange={this.ic_noChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.ic_no}/>
    </div>
</div> : null

}
```

After having check of citizenship with out entering adhar number or passport number not showing alert

May I know what am I doing wrong.

Is this not the proper way to do

I have updated the quotation with html and onchange event

Comment: Can u post the HTML -render method plus state/constructor code

Comment: It seems like you are not setting a value for `this.state.citizenship`. Please post the complete component that you are writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something wrong with the conditions. Tried to simplify the code (not able to test). i think it will work.

```
submit(){

    if(this.state.citizenship == ""){
        alert("Please Select Citizenship");
        return;
    }
    else {
      if(this.state.citizenship == "Indian" ){
            if(this.state.ic_no == ""){
                alert("Enter Adhar Number");
                return;
            }
       }
       else if(this.state.citizenship == "Foreigner") {
            if (this.state.passport_no == "" ){
                alert("Enter Passport Number");
                return;
            }
       }
    }

    //Now all checks are done use the data 
    let data ={
         ic_no: this.state.ic_no,
         passport_no: this.state.passport_no,
         citizenship: this.state.citizenship
    }

  }
```

Comment: In else data object should be there, If I keep your else in else if, It is showing error

Answer (score 0):

Many things could be improved in your component's composition.

1. Define the `state` in `constructor` if you want to define it the way you have defined else define without the use of `this`.
2. `if` condition evaluation is correct but it seems you have not prevent the default behavior of form `onSubmit` event. So, use `e.preventDefault()` and do `return` to stop further execution.

Let me try to re-create a more readable and terse version of your component using the above given snippet.

```
// <-- YourComponent.js -->
// Assumption: No redux used to maintain the component states

import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class YourComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            citizenship: '',
            passport_no: '',
            ic_no: ''
        };
    }

    handleOnChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    };

    handleOnSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { citizenship, passport_no, ic_no } = this.state;
        // field level validation STARTS
        if(!citizenship){
            alert("Please select Citizenship");
            return;
        } else {
            if (!ic_no && !passport_no) {
                alert("Please enter Aadhaar and Passport Number");
                return;
            } else if(!ic_no) {
                alert("Please enter Aadhaar Number");
                return;
            } else if(!passport_no) {
                alert("Please enter Passport Number");
                return;
            }
        }
        // field level validation ENDS

        // Safe to submit the data to server here
        const data = { citizenship, passport_no, ic_no };
    };

    render() {
        const { citizenship, passport_no, ic_no } = this.state;

        return (
            <form
                action="javascript:void(0);"
                onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}
            >
                <div className="form-group row p-l-5">
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="radio"
                                name="citizenship"
                                value="Indian"
                                checked={citizenship && citizenship === 'Indian'}
                                onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                            /> &nbsp;
                            <label>Indian</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="radio"
                                name="citizenship"
                                value="Foreigner"
                                checked={citizenship && citizenship === 'Foreigner'}
                                onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                            /> &nbsp;
                            <label>Foreigner</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {(citizenship && citizenship === 'Foreigner') && (
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label className="col-md-12">Passport No</label>
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <input
                                className="form-control"
                                type="text"
                                name="passport_no"
                                value={passport_no}
                                onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
                {(citizenship && citizenship === 'Indian') && (
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label className="col-md-12">IC No</label>
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <input
                                className="form-control"
                                type="text"
                                name="ic_no"
                                value={ic_no}
                                onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
                <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    type="submit"
                >
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```